# mount google compute engine directory on local system

Tags: google-compute-engine, sshfs, mount-point

Can we mount google compute engine directory on local system using sshfs or any other alternative ?
Can we mount google compute engine directory on local system using sshfs or any other alternative ?

Sorry, i had to repeat question otherwise SOF was not allowing me to post question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mount mount google compute engine directory on local system using sshfs. You’ll need to first install FUSE and configure autofs or sshfs. Here is a [guide](https://www.tjansson.dk/2008/01/autofs-and-sshfs-the-perfect-couple/) you can look at to start this up.